# What is IPython automagic?

Tags: ipython

What is IPython automagic?  I have looked everywhere and I cant find a definition.

Example:

> If you have ‘automagic’ enabled (as it by default), you don’t need to
>   type in the single % explicitly for line magics; IPython will scan its
>   internal list of magic functions and call one if it exists. With
>   automagic on you can then just type cd mydir to go to directory
>   ‘mydir’:

Source http://ipython.org/ipython-doc/dev/interactive/reference.html

Comment: This is an IPhython specific and nothing to do with the python language spec.

Comment: and only affects the console. ipython has some console directives like %prun (which runs the following command in the profiler), and users can define their own. automagic just lets you type `prun function(arg1, arg2)` instead of `%prun function(arg1, arg2)` but you can't use these in scripts.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In IPython, magics are a special (non-Python) syntax for performing certain actions, such as:

```
%run myscript.py
```

or

```
%cd /path/to/something
```

If `automagic` is on, then IPython will add the leading `%` if you leave it out, allowing you to do things like:

```
run myscript.py
```

or

```
cd /path/to/something
```

If you disable automagics, then you might see things like this:

```
In [1]: %automagic 0

Automagic is OFF, % prefix IS needed for line magics.

In [2]: cd path
  File "<ipython-input-2-ed35da3eb5b7>", line 1
    cd path
          ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

But it does allow you to be extra explicit about what functionality is provided by IPython, and what is provided by Python itself.